# Trouble getting collections working with github pages

Tags: collections, jekyll, github-pages

there.

Here's my config.yaml:

```
# Permalinks
permalink:        pretty
relative_permalinks: true

# Setup
title:            Tom Critchlow Title
tagline:          My Github Site
url:              http://tomcritchlow.com
paginate:         1
baseurl:          /
author:
  name:           Tom Critchlow
  url:            https://twitter.com/tomcritchlow
  email:          tjcritchlow@gmail.com


collections:
  - poetry:
    output: true
```

And here's my folder structure:

```
-config.yaml
-index.html
-archive.md
_layouts
_poetry
_posts
```

Yet on my archive page when I do this:

```
{% for poem in site.poetry %}
  hello world
{% endfor %}
```

Nothing happens... I'm also struggling to render anything in my poetry collection.

You can see the github repo here:

https://github.com/tomcritchlow/tomcritchlow.github.io

What am I doing wrong? How do you get collections working on Github pages? I'm totally new to github. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had `config.yaml` instead of `_config.yaml`

Comment: Damn.... You're right. This fixed things right up. Thank you! Told you I was a n00b at github

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you github repository gave me some ideas about your problem**s**.

First, answering to your question, your `config.yaml` file **MUST** be named `_config.yml` if you want Jekyll to take it into account.

**But**, there is a lot of other issues all over you site (empty `_layouts/default.html`, no `_layouts/page.html`, `_layouts/blog.html` as no front matter, `baseurl/` set to `/` instead of `""`,...).

I really think it's better to work on an new clean version and copy you content to it.

- `gem update`
- make a new working folder eg: `mkdir newjekyll`
- go to it
- `jekyll new .`
- copy your content to your new jekyll including your collection
- `jekyll serve`
- all will be ok on 127.0.0.1:4000/